# Volume by double or triple integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I was trying to integrate the volume of a body blocked by $z=0,\; z=2x,\; x+y = 3$ and $y=0$ using the double integral... however it didn't work yet.

I'm convinced its a double integral and not a triple one.  Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: You *do* need a triple integral.

Comment: find the area of crosssection on the surface $z=z_0$ first.

Comment: Once a volume has been setup as a triple integral (the main difficulty of which is getting the nested limits of integration), performing the inner integration converts it to a double integration.  So your intuition is right, but sometimes it is more expeditious just to use an approach you know will work and let the mechanical process create a better insight.

Answer (score 1):

From the given equations of the blocking planes we can see that for given $x$, $y$ gets all values from $0$ to $3-x$ and $z$ from $0$ to $2x$. Values of $x$ are restricted to the interval from $0$ to $3$ so the volume is given by the triple integral
$$V = \int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{3-x}\int_{0}^{2x} 1dzdydx = \int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{3-x}2x dydx = \int_{0}^{3} 2x(3-x) dydx = \int_{0}^{3} 6x-2x^2 dydx
= 3x^2-\frac{2}{3}x^3|_{0}^{3} = 9. $$

Answer (score 0):

The volume under a function (in our case $z=2x$) is a double integral:
$$
\int_0^3\int_0^{3-y}zdxdy=\int_0^3\int_0^{3-y}2xdxdy=\int_0^3\left[x^2\right]_0^{3-y}dy=\int_0^3\left(3-y\right)^2dy=-\frac{1}{3}\left[\left(3-y\right)^2\right]_0^{3}=-\frac{1}{3}\left[0-9\right]=3
$$